# TDBGrid com MultiSelect selecionado com um Clique

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou passando pelo seguinte problema com um `TDBGrid`.

Essa `TDBGrid` está com a opção `dgMultiSelect` ativa. O problema é, quero que, com um clique a linha fique selecionada como se tivesse apertado ***Ctrl*** + **Mouse click** e é isso que não sei como fazer.

- Código :

  ```
  procedure TfrmPrincipal.GridCellClick(Column: TColumn);
  var
    sValorColunaAtivo: Integer;
  begin
    if UpperCase(Column.FieldName) = 'SELECTED' then
    begin
      if DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.FieldByName('SELECTED').AsInteger = 1 then
        sValorColunaAtivo := 0
      else
        sValorColunaAtivo := 1;
      // edita o DataSet, inverte o status e grava os dados
      DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.Edit;
      DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.FieldByName('SELECTED').AsInteger := sValorColunaAtivo;
      DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.Post;
    end;
  end;
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca assim que vai dar certo.

1. Você simula o `ctrl + MouseClick`.
2. Você desenvolve seu Código.
3. Você simula o `ctrl` sendo liberado.

Código:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.GridCellClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  sValorColunaAtivo: Integer;
begin
  keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,0,0); // Mantém pressionada CTRL
  if UpperCase(Column.FieldName) = 'SELECTED' then
  begin
    if DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.FieldByName('SELECTED').AsInteger = 1 then
      sValorColunaAtivo := 0
    else
      sValorColunaAtivo := 1;
    // edita o DataSet, inverte o status e grava os dados
    DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.Edit;
    DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.FieldByName('SELECTED').AsInteger := sValorColunaAtivo;
    DM.FDMemTableExpedicao.Post;
  end;
  keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, $45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // Libera (solta) CTRL
end;
```

Desse modo fica certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria pintar a linha que o usuário selecionou através do evento OnDrawColumnCell.

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.GridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
begin

  if DM.FDMemTableExpedicaoSELECTED.AsInteger = 1 then
  begin
    Grid.canvas.Brush.color := clBlue; // Pinta o fundo da linha de azul
    Grid.Canvas.Font.color := clWhite; // Pinta a fonte de branco
  end;

  Grid.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, column.field, state);
end;
```

Comment: boa ideia mais a questão da contagem dos itens selecionados ainda vai perder.

Comment: @EduMendonça por que perderia? Esse evento só está pintando a linha, você consegue pegar sem problemas os itens ou a contagem pelo Grid ou DataSet do Grid.

Comment: Eu testei só que não conta quantos estão selecionados.